# Is it possible to select programatically a row in AnyGantt charts?

Tags: javascript, gantt-chart, anychart

Let's say we have a simple Gantt chart, implemented in JavaScript, using [AnyChart](https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Overview) library:

[image: Simple Gantt chart]

If the user clicks on *Tuesday* row, it's automatically highlighted:

[image: Highlighted row]

**Is it possible to do it programatically?** I mean, I don't want the user to click on a row, I want to do it with code.

AnyChart provides a wonderful playground to test the library. I created one to have a starting point: [Select a row programatically](https://playground.anychart.com/fwa91Th8/5). In the JavaScript code, search for the `selectRow` function, and do your magic.

```js
function selectRow() {
  const idToSelect = "3";
  const selected = treeData.search("id", idToSelect);
  // highlight selected item
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you should apply `true` to the `selected` field of the item meta. For details, check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/eOCPqz3h).

Comment: Great! `selected.meta("selected", true)` works perfect in the example I provided. But in the project I'm working on, it still doesn't work. We identified it's due to a custom mapping we use with `treeData.mapAs()`. In this [example with mapping](https://playground.anychart.com/64zWbbsu/1), I set the data to the chart with a custom mapping and the highlight doesn't work.

Comment: Got it! As a default, the Gantt chart is based on the dataTree. But if you are applying a custom mapping, then the item should be searched and modified in the mapping instance, not the tree. For details, check the modified sample by the following link - https://playground.anychart.com/F6jMoWkX